# Make Tableau automatically recognize a numeric field as geographic role?

Tags: tableau-api, geography

I have a two numeric fields one is called Lat and the other is called Long (see the attached image). When tableau reads the data, it assigns the geo role (as indicated by the data symbol) to the field of Lat but not the Long field. Is there a way I can make Tableau AUTOMATICALLY assign the geo role to the field of Long too?

[image]

I understand that I can always manually switch a field to the geographic data type or used the field of Longitude (generated). However, for my particular task on hand, it is best I can just use the field of Long as geographic data automatically.

If this information helps: The original dataset is based on a Txt file. The Lat and Long field in the original Txt file are String datatype, they were then transformed to Double in an ETL software.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Name your field **Longitude** instead of Long, and Tableau will automatically assign it the appropriate geographic role.

You might want to then also use Latitude instead of Lat for consistency.